# Do we have $| \langle f, \psi \rangle_{L^2} | \le C_j \| f \|_{\mathcal{C}^2} \| \psi \|_{1}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, wavelets

For $j,k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $c > 0$ define
$$
\psi_{\lambda}(x)
:= \psi_{j,k,m}(x_1,x_2)
:= 2^{3j/4} \psi(S_k A_{2^j} x - cm),
$$
where $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and
$$
A_{2^j} := \begin{pmatrix} 2^{j} & 0 \\ 0 & 2^{j/2} \end{pmatrix}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
S_k := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
In ["Compactly supported shearlets are optimally sparse" by Prof. Kutyniok and Wang Q.-Lim](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273472615_Compactly_Supported_Shearlets_are_Optimally_Sparse) on page 1576 (section 2.3) it says that if we assume $\| \psi \|_1 < 1$ we have
$$
| \langle f, \psi_{\lambda} \rangle |
\le 2^{-3j/4},
$$
where $f \in \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with $\| f \|_{\mathcal{C}^2} = \sum_{| \alpha | \le 2} \| D^{\alpha} f \|_{\infty} \le 1$.

**My try:**
We have
\begin{align}
| \langle f, \psi_{\lambda} \rangle |
& = 2^{3j/4} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x_1, x_2) \psi(S_k A_{2^j} x - cm) dx \right| \\
& \le 2^{3j/4} \| f \|_{\mathcal{C}^2} \| \psi(S_k A_{2^j} \cdot - cm) \|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)} \tag{?} \\
& \le 2^{3j/4} \underbrace{\| f \|_{\mathcal{C}^2}}_{\le 1} \cdot 2^{-3j/2} \underbrace{\| \psi \|_{1}}_{< 1}
\le 2^{-3j/4}.
\end{align}
I am very unsure of step (?). Is it correct? If no, can we take a similar approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written is fine. From the comments, the key clarification is that since $\|f\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_{C^2}$ we can conclude that 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(x_1,x_2) \psi(S_k A_{2^j} x - cm)| dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \|f\|_\infty |\psi(S_k A_{2^j} x - cm)| dx \leq \|f\|_{C^2} \|\psi(S_kA_{2^j} \cdot - cm) \|_1.$$